# "Oblivion" as a state of forgetfulness?

Tags: meaning

I usually think of "oblivion" as referring to a state of being forgotten, as in the expression "consign to oblivion".  [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblivion#Noun) includes this definition, but also gives "The state of forgetfulness or distraction" as another definition.  Is this actually true?  Can someone give an example where "oblivion" is used to mean forgetfulness rather than forgotten-ness?

Comment: Per the NOAD, "They drank themselves into oblivion"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oblivion), the definition of Oblivion you're looking for is:

> ***oblivion***: *noun*
>
> *The state of being unaware or unconscious of what is happening around one*

And some examples of oblivion implying forgetfulness are:

> *Brad only groaned once as Kurt and Vincent lifted him between them,
>   and then the dark and painless unconscious oblivion claimed him again.*
>
> *Our sages teach us that our oblivion, our unawareness of the full
>   ramifications of every harsh word and action, lasts only until the day
>   of death.*
>
> *The oblivion of unconsciousness was creeping up on her at its leisure,
>   and she would make him regret murdering her too slowly.*

And, just to clarify further, some examples of oblivion implying "forgotten-ness":

> *For the unsuccessful ones, their ordeal simply fades into public oblivion.*
>
> *And like the unperfected Polaroid of a beginning we've forgotten, it should fade into oblivion in no time.*
>
> *So yet another great album was destined to fade into oblivion, before being picked up on by a few musos, plundered for sounds and style,
>   hailed in retrospect as a classic and finally reissued on CD.*

Comment: Interesting.  I think I've seen the word used this way before, but it didn't occur to me.  I wonder which meaning came first.